# What does XmlPullParser "eventType" indicate?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am documenting some code using JD-GUI. Currently working on class that utilizes "XMLPullParser". I have read some documentation, but not really getting a clear picture.

The following is a snippet from a method, I want to know what this "eventType" is indication before and in the switch statement cases. What is the significance of it? The "parser" variable below is of type "XmlPullParser"

```
  while (!poComplete)
  {
  int eventType = this.parser.next();
  if (1 == eventType) {
    break;
  }
  switch (eventType)
  {
  case 2: 
    String name = this.parser.getName();
    if ("purchaseOrder".equals(name)) {
      bufferingData = true;
    }
    if (bufferingData) {
      buf.append("<").append(name).append(">");
    }
    break;
  case 3: 
    if (bufferingData)
    {
      String name = this.parser.getName();
      buf.append("</").append(name).append(">");
      if ("purchaseOrder".equals(name))
      {
        poComplete = true;
        bufferingData = false;
      }
    }
    break;
  case 4: 
    if (bufferingData) {
      buf.append(quoteXmlData(this.parser.getText()));
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next() method returns eventType of integer.

it is one of the constants defined in XMLPullParser.

see [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#next())